# multiline cell: sum the second line of each cell

Tags: google-sheets, indexing

I need to sum the second line of every cell from a range.

- Every line is separated by char(10)
- Some cells doesn't have 1st, 2nd or 3rd line

I've tried to split and index 2nd row, I'm capable for 1 cell but not for the entire range.

[image]

Comment: What do yo mean with "don't have x line" exactly? No line separators as well, or are the separators there always?

Comment: Some lines are empty, but separated by char(10) (red coloured cells)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with this formula that SPLITs the values by CHAR(10), with INDEX grabs the second value. With BYCOL repeats the process for each of the three columns. SUMs them, and finally repeats the process for each row with BYROW:

```
=BYROW(B2:D,LAMBDA(r,IF(COUNTA(r)=0,,
SUM(BYCOL(r,LAMBDA(each,INDEX(SPLIT(each,CHAR(10),1,0),,2)))))))
```

[image]

Comment: this works as a charm, thanks!

Answer (score -1):

*You may test:*

```js
=sum(index(iferror(--regexextract(B3:D3,"\n.*"))))
```

[image]

Comment: this works too on this example